# Create angular directive like ngDisabled to check roles in list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-disabled

I want to create an attribute directive like ngDisabled to enable or disable elements if some specific role is present on my service.

```
angular.module(...)
.service('RolesSerivce', function() {
    this.hasRole = function(roleName) {
         return this.roles.indexOf(roleName)>1;
    };
    this.setRoles = function(rolesArr) {
        this.roles = rolesArr;
    };
    this.setRoles(['ROLE_CAN_CLICK'])
}).direcive('hasRole', function() {
    ??????????????????
    // use RolesSerivce.hasRole inside implemetation
    ??????????????????
});
```

On my HTML I want to use the directive like this:

```
<button has-role="ROLE_CAN_CLICK" ng-disabled="extraValidation > 0">Click me</button>
```

On the example above, the `has-role` directive must override the `ng-disable`, it must be mandatory. But the `ng-disable` must run when the `has-role` is `true`.

My question, can someone help me with the directive implementation? How can I do this?

### Example with bug

http://codepen.io/betonetotbo/pen/rrazzY

Comment: What mean *directive must override the ng-disable*?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko It must be mandatory, if there are an ng-disabled it must be overrided by my directive, in case, must be ignored.

Comment: Do you want the button disabled when `ROLE_CAN_CLICK` is false?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
angular.module(...)
.service('RolesService', function() {
    this.hasRole = function(roleName) {
         return this.roles.indexOf(roleName)>1;
    };
    this.setRoles = function(rolesArr) {
        this.roles = rolesArr;
    };
    this.setRoles(['ROLE_CAN_CLICK'])
}).directive('hasRole', function(RolesService) {
    return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).removeAttr('ng-disabled');
        if(RoleService.hasRole(attrs.hasRole)) {
            $(element).removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $(element).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }           
    }
    };
});
```

Comment: This will not work, I need to leave ng-disabled running if it has the role. Can you provide a https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Create a truth table:

```
                      (extraValidation > 0)==true  (extraValidation > 0)==false

ROLE_CAN_CLICK==true        DISABLED                     ENABLED

ROLE_CAN_CLICK==false       DISABLED                     DISABLED
```

Create an expression that matches the truth table:

```
<button ng-disabled="(!ROLE_CAN_CLICK) || (extraValidation > 0)">
     Click me
</button>
```